# Fill repeated grid by http service/Action in orbeon 4.5

Tags: service, grid, action, orbeon

I'm trying to fill a repeated grid in orbeon with a XML file and http service/action. The xml looks like this:

```
<result>
    <code>Row 1</code>
    <code>Row 2</code>
    <code>Row 3</code>
</result>
```

But only the first row is filled and no row is dynamically added to repeated grid. What step is missng?

Thx!

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Currently the action editor is only able to set return values to the "current" repeat row (the one with the current index).

In Orbeon Forms 4.7 we have a yet undocumented feature, and which does not have a user interface, to call the service n times, once per repeat row. It's not completely ideal, as if you have 10 rows, you will get 10 service calls.

But this will be only with 4.7, and maybe you would like to avoid the multiple service calls anyway.

Other than that, you will need to write custom XForms.

Comment: And see also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/6518825#file-gistfile1-html-L115) for inspiration. It uses custom XForms in response to the service call to perform insertions.