# fill a repeated grid from a SQL database in Orbeon 4.10

Tags: sql, orbeon, xforms

Im trying to fill a repeated grid from a SQL database in Orbeon 4.10. My actions/Database service are (i think) setup correctly because it does work for a single row of my repeated grid. I would like to add the right amount of row to my grid based on the result of my query.

check comments for my db services and actions.
here is my source code : http://dumptext.com/Oh7WG2mp

I did search around and found a mention of an undocumented feature in 4.7 that would allow that here :
[Fill repeated grid by http service/Action in orbeon 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972198/fill-repeated-grid-by-http-service-action-in-orbeon-4-5)

Is this documented now or do I have to write some custom xform?

Comment: Actions : http://anonm.gr/?353e.png

Comment: DB : http://anonmgur.com/up/40e220ae39063cbf00b961b3e7a06c77.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not possible via the UI yet but there is an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1298) for this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so I would have to write custom xform behind the form? Can you point me to some resource on how to do that?

Comment: No answer, if it make it easier i dont really need it to be done via an action, i can be loaded via a button. Can you point me to some ressource ?

Comment: It's quite a bit of XForms code to do by hand and properly, and it might break in the future. The undocumented feature you are referring to got implemented [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/eb192dea75272b07bfeb4018bccdcca35f17fd1d).

Comment: The way it works is adding a special `var` before the `send` in the action implementation:

    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed xforms-enabled" ev:observer="foo-control"
               if="true()">
        <xf:var name="iterate-control-name" value="'bar'"/>
        <xf:send submission="my-service-submission"/>
    </xf:action>

Comment: But I am not sure this is ideal, again this will call the service multiple times, with different values from each row. Ideally we would really just have an action to populate the grid based on what the SQL service returns.

Comment: Thanks @ebruchez, i was able to acheive what i wanted using this workaround and a (hidden) autoincrement field in my repeat.

Comment: Excellent, and sorry this is so hard to do.